# do you need WOFF if you have TFF in electron applications

Tags: electron, truetype, woff, woff2

I'm setting up an electron application in React and unlike web do I still need to use
eot | woff | woff2 if I'm using TFF from google.

I know if web browsers I have to use them all for backward capability but unsure for electron applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron comes with the Chromium Browser. So whatever works in Chromium works in Electron. Browser compatibility is not necessary.

Comment: That makes sense but why would a TTF not work on Chromium Browser running on electron PC.

Comment: If a TTF is not rendered in Electron it has something to do with your code. Normally I use local files as generating and downloading the font from google every time can cause issues. Also I use WOFF or WOFF2 as I prefer them over the bulky TTF fonts.